# iOS 7 navigation bar jumping / stretching upon viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar

I am trying to update my app for iOS 7. When my views appear on the screen, you can see that there is a gap between the navigation bar and the rest of the screen, and then the navigation bar "jumps" or "stretches" to fill the gap. This is causing my custom UIBarButtonItems to fall off the navigation bar. I tried to take a photo of the transition but it happens before the camera can take the picture. I have attached a picture of what happens to the button, however. Thanks for any advice. Please let me know if any code would be of help. [image: picture of button falling]

Comment: Have you assigned the button to be your top left button for your UINavigationBar?

Comment: I changed the way the button gets put on the screen so it is now sticking to the nav bar. I used a custom button and then initialized at UIBarButtonItem with that button. Then I set the leftBarButtonItem on the nav bar to be the UIBarButtonItem. I would still appreciate any insight as to why the nav bar appears to jump / stretch when the view appears.

Comment: Could you post the code in which you did this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason why this occurs. It is answered in this pre-existing SO answer: [iOS7 UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal bounces after transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781519/ios7-uimodaltransitionstylefliphorizontal-bounces-after-transition). The concept is that I was setting the modal transition style to flip horizontal, and apparently that doesn't work correctly in iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

Hello there is a Problem in the ios 7 with navigation bar ,Navigation bar appear over the views or showing gap between the  nav bar and view , You  can solved this problem with the help of following code

There has been a new property introduced in iOS 7 that lets you adjust the layout behavior as in previous versions of iOS. this  code in your view controller, and you should be good The space your navigation bar takes up should be accounted for automatically

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Thanks

Comment: I have tried using such a call, but that doesn't seem to solve the issue. The issue still exists when a modal view controller is presented. I used this code to try to combat the issue:                                      listVC.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
listVC.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;