# Navigation bar jumps out from under status bar?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios7

I have a button in my main view controller that pushes a navigation controller with an embedded view controller using a segue.

When the new view controller is presented, the navigation bar on it briefly appears under the status bar. (The status bar is not hidden.) The contents (which are relative to the top layout guide) are in the correct location. As soon as the animation is complete, it fixes itself.

When the view is dismissed again, the same thing happens: the main view controller briefly overwrites the status bar. For the main view controller, this is a little more significant as it's based on a `UITableViewController`; the entire table jumps. Again, when the animation is complete the view controller fixes itself.

I've tried turning off translucency on the navigation bar, but it only makes the problem more obvious. All of this works as expected on iOS 6.

I've uploaded a minimalist test case here: https://github.com/tewha/FlipTest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another simple trick is do this:

In the **MasterViewController**

When is preparing for Segue:

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.navigationController.view
                      duration:0.75
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                    animations:nil
                    completion:nil];
}
```

And when Unwind the **AboutViewController**

```
- (IBAction)aboutUnwind:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {

[UIView transitionWithView:((UIViewController *)segue.sourceViewController).view
                  duration:0.75
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                animations:nil
                completion:nil];
```

}

Comment: Prepare for segue is called after 'performSegueWithIdentifier:'.  Your storyboard will trigger transition and in prepare for segue is meant for some last minute changes.  To make this a more legitimate solution, rather than a hack, you should do as I suggest below.

Comment: Thanks #robdashnash, I'm going to check your comment and link.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the layout system of iOS7. I found that reducing the height of the navigation controller's view (not the pushed view controller's!) by the status bar height and placing it in y = status bar height will help a lot, but there will still be a small flicker where the status bar "merges" with the navigation controller.

As a side not, see if the bug still exists in iOS7.1b1.

Comment: If this truly is an iOS bug, I think I'll just live with it. It's only cosmetic and as soon as Apple includes a fix, my users will get it. Annoying, though. :)

Comment: I'm going to accept doorbatta's answer because his workaround is simpler. I think you might want to have a look at it, too. :) But thank you.

Comment: I am aware of this. Doesn't help in my case.

Comment: Why my workaround didn't work for you? Are you using presentModal?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Problem in the ios 7 with navigation bar ,Navigation bar appear over the views or showing gap between the nav bar and view , You can solved this problem with the help of following code

There has been a new property introduced in iOS 7 that lets you adjust the layout behavior as in previous versions of iOS. this code in your view controller, and you should be good The space your navigation bar takes up should be accounted for automatically

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Answer obtained from [iOS 7 navigation bar jumping / stretching upon viewDidAppear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191609/ios-7-navigation-bar-jumping-stretching-upon-viewdidappear)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in UK kit.  Avoid using the standard methods

'performSegueWithIdentifier' or 'presentViewController'

Here I transition from one controller to another, then transition back in the delegate callback, using UIView transition animations.

```
-(void)photoButtonPressed:(NSNotification*)notification
{        
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Media"
                                                         bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *navCon = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

    PhotoCaptureViewController *controller = navCon.viewControllers.firstObject;
    controller.delegate = self;

    CustomTabBarViewController *tabBarController = (CustomTabBarViewController*)self.tabBarController;

    [UIView transitionWithView:self.navigationController.view duration:0.75 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^{
                        [tabBarController.parentViewController addChildViewController:navCon];
                        [tabBarController.parentViewController.view addSubview:navCon.view];
                    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                        [navCon didMoveToParentViewController:tabBarController.parentViewController];
                    }];
}

-(void)photoCaptureViewController:(PhotoCaptureViewController *)controller dismissButtonPressed:(UIButton *)dismissButton
{
    CustomTabBarViewController *tabBarController = (CustomTabBarViewController*)self.tabBarController;

    [UIView transitionFromView:controller.navigationController.view toView:tabBarController.view duration:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [controller.navigationController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
        [controller.navigationController removeFromParentViewController];
        [controller.navigationController.view removeFromSuperview];
    }];

}
```

This is a great read about container views [Khanlou's blog post](http://khanlou.com/2012/11/container-view-controllers/)