# Horizontal flip animation produces gap between title bar and view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, animation, autolayout

I am buidling a very simple look up app. The first screen of the app is doing a horizontal flip animation. I have done this using a storyboard. There is no code implemented to have this animated. It looks great, however I have a black gap between the title bar and table view. Note, I don't have any code in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`. Any idea why it is ending up with this gap? The gap closes after the view finishes loading.

[image]

Comment: I just noticed I have the same problem and I'm having a brain fart on how to fix it. Any solutions?

Comment: No mate i am still waiting for an answer...

Comment: Which version of iOS / Xcode is this on? Can you show the Storyboard so I can see how to recreate it.

Comment: I have the same problem. I just tried to recreate it with Xcode 6 storyboards with size-classes but wasn't able to. My non-working version is compiled with iOS 7.1 as Base SDK, an iPhone-only storyboard with a simple button that transitions with a modal presentation (transition:"Flip horizontally") from a standard view controller to a navigation controller containing a standard view controller.

Comment: One more thing: I only have the black bar when animation to the navigation controller, not when animating back to the original view controller, also it just looks like a reverse animation.

Comment: Regarding the Xcode version: I'm compiling with Xcode 6 by now, but the project was created with Xcode 5. I'm not able to recreate the problem in a new project, but it persists in an existing one, even when using Xcode 6.

Comment: @Fogmeister I managed to reproduce it with Xcode 6. The missing part was to make the navigation bar of the backside navigation controller be non-transparent (deactivated checkmark in storyboard). I did this in my original project as the transparent case made the complete bar black during the animation, so making it non-transparent was an improvement. You can find the project here and play around with it: https://github.com/JoachimKurz/FlipApp

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the problem by stopping the navigation bar from animating in. If that is a suitable solution for you, you can stop the navigation bar's animation following the solution in [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781519/ios7-uimodaltransitionstylefliphorizontal-bounces-after-transition):

Override viewWillAppear in the view controller you are transitioning **to**, like so:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer removeAllAnimations];
}
```

However, this is only a workaround not a proper solution for the root cause, I think.

Comment: Was it created in a xib? I know this possibly isn't a solution but have you "updated" the xib to be an Xcode 6 only xib?

Comment: Yes, it's all setup in a storyboard, no code to do the animation (apart from the bit added in this answer). I'm not sure what you mean by "upgraded to Xcode 6 only". The IB-Version displayed in the inspector ("Opens in") is Xcode 6. But it doesn't use size classes yet.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant.