# UINavigationBar jumping down when segueing between UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, ios7, uiviewcontroller, nslayoutconstraint

My iOS 7 app is segueing between to view controllers with Style set to Modal and Transition Style set to Flip Horizontal. The app's Status Bar Style is set to Default.

Before the transition the status bar is visible and the navigation bar as well as the first view appear below it, as they should.

After the transition the status bar is visible and the navigation as well as the second view eventually also appears below it. But this is only after a short (yet perceptible and hence distracting) animation whereby the navigation bar apparently jumps down from the top of the screen (i.e. shifts by the hight of the status bar). The second view does not jump: it apparently resides at its correct layout position right from the start.

So far I have left the second view controller's layout-related properties at their default values (see below).

Why does this animation occur and how can it be avoided?

[image]

Comment: If you have your status bar hidden on one view controller and presented on another you will experience this sort of issues as no UI will be updated until transition is complete.

Comment: But the status bar is visible in the first view controller and I'm doing nothing to hide it. Are you saying that the hiding is implicit in this sort of transition? If so, can it be avoided e.g. by configuration?

Comment: you have to take a look into your `viewDidLoad` , `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` methods on your second `viewController` if there is a piece of code that updates your User Interface this will be executed after the transition as well. Take a look there as well

Comment: No worries man. Are you using `Autolayout` in your storyboard?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS7 UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal bounces after transition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781519/ios7-uimodaltransitionstylefliphorizontal-bounces-after-transition)

Comment: @PanayotPanayotov Yes, I am. I've now found the answer (apparently a bug in UIKit) and marked this question as duplicate. Re-thx.

Comment: @Drux It would be really nice if you could post the answer to this question. I am struggling with the same issue.

Comment: @SAHM See references to UIKit bug in answers to linked duplicate question.